# Why is CSS positioning not behaving as expected with this table?

Tags: css, css-position

What I'd expect from the HTML below is that I'd see `woo1` and `woo2` overlapping while `hiiii` remains in its own cell away from the woos.  However, everything runs together.  Why?

http://jsfiddle.net/T4Jgx/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="position:relative">
            <span style="position:absolute">woo1</span>
            <span style="position:absolute">woo2</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>hiiii</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Edit:**  Weird.  When I remove the style from `woo2`, it appears to work.  When I remove it from `woo1`, `woo2` overlaps `hiiii`.  Da fu...?

**Edit2:**  For Reconstruct, your comment has to do with tables, so how come the exact same effect can be reproduced with this?

```
<div>
    <span style="position:relative">
        <span style="position:absolute">woo1</span>
        <span style="position:absolute">woo2</span>
    </span>
    <span>hiiii</span>
</div>
```

**Edit3:**  Arrghh... I believe I understand what is happening.  By adding absolute positioning to the two spans, they are removed from the control flow and the first TD is collapsed.  I am thinking about deleting this question, but maybe someone can just confirm what I just said and get the answer?

Comment: From the [2.1 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position): *The effect of 'position: relative' on table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group, table-column, **table-cell**, and table-caption elements is undefined.*

Comment: The contents of an absolutely positioned element do not flow around any other boxes, regardless of whether there is a relatively positioned ancestor or not. It is removed from the normal flow entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your `TD` content in a `DIV` and transfer `position:relative` to that.

```
<td>
    <div style="position:relative">
            <span style="position:absolute">woo1</span>
            <span style="position:absolute">woo2</span>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: This is exactly the same thing I did in my latest edit.  However, I believe I am starting to understand what is happening.

Comment: Absolutely-positioned elements are no longer part of the document flow. You need to supply a height to the DIV to keep your cell from collapsing.